# How to write a definition of the non-dependent product using Pi types in Lean?

Tags: dependent-type, theorem-proving, formal-verification, lean

I'm working through [chapter 7 – Inductive Types](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/#07_Inductive_Types.html) of "Theorem Proving in Lean".

I'd like to know how to write the definition of <s>dependent</s> non-dependent product in a more expanded or "primitive" form.

1. It looks like the definition given in the tutorial automatically infers some detail:

   `inductive prod1 (α : Type u) (β : Type v)
   | mk : α → β → prod1`
2. Some experimentation allows to fill in the detail 
   `inductive prod2 (α : Type u) (β : Type v) : Type (max u v)
   | mk : α → β → prod2`
3. However giving the definition in a fully expand form, using Pi types fails to typecheck:

   `inductive prod3 : Π (α : Type u) (β : Type v), Type (max u v)
   | mk : α → β → prod3`

What is the correct way to write `prod3`?

Finally, is the following definition equivalent to `prod1` and `prod2`, i.e. can the type checker always infer the correct type universe for `α` and `β`?

4. `inductive prod4 (α : Type) (β : Type)
   | mk : α → β → prod4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, note that there is nothing dependent about your types. *Dependent product* is just another name for the Pi type itself (the Pi deriving from the usual mathematical notation for indexed products).

Your `prod2` type is the correct maximally explicit version of `prod1`. In `prod3`, you changed α and β from inductive *parameters* to *indices*, which as you noticed doesn't work out for universe-related reasons. In general, indices are used to define inductive type families as in section 7.7.

Finally, the atomic `Type` you used in `prod4` is an abbreviation of `Type 1`. You can use `Type*` to have universe parameters inferred automatically.